# how to change url using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to show the URL

http://www.example.com/blog/feedback
as

http://www.example.com/feedback

How can I do so using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/feedback$ /blog/feedback
</IfModule>
```

Have a look [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/) for a tutorial information on mod_rewrite.

**EDIT**:

If you are trying to move JUST `/blog/feedback` to `/feedback` then you will have to first move your base from `/app/webroot/blog/` to `/app/webroot/`, edit all your rules to account for it and then add your new rule. Could be done like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /app/webroot/

  RewriteRule ^/blog/index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^/blog/feedback$ /feedback [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule /blog /app/webroot/blog/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

NB: This should work, but I'm not at my work station right now so I can't check it :( If anything goes wrong it's probably a typo somewhere - let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !!!

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/webroot/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /app/webroot/blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

this is my htaccess how can i rewrite the htacess feedback

Comment: Please help 

`code` # BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /app/webroot/blog/ RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /app/webroot/blog/index.php [L] </IfModule> # `code`

Comment: Edited the question - hope the answer helps. I see you're new to stackoverflow, tip for the future: include your code in the question, not in the comments :) If you need to, you can always edit the question :)